# How to Unzip data in NET Core 3.1 that was Compressed Using Ionic Zip (Without using Ionic to unzip)

Tags: c#, compression, asp.net-core-3.1, ionic-zip

Our system has multiple applications and one of them compresses text using Ionic Zip and saves the byte array to the database.

We are working on a different app built using NET Core 3.1 and I'd like access to this data but don't want to use the Ionic Zip package to get the access since it isn't built for Core 3.1.

I'd like to do this in memory and have tried each of the 3 decompression stream types available in System.IO.Compression and all claim the data was compressed using  an unsupported method.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Comment: Which ionic-zip API did you use, exactly? for example, if you used `ZipFile`, then this maps to `ZipArchive` in `System.IO.Compression`. An illustration of how **exactly** you encoded the data would help a lot.

Comment: Ioniz Zip was deprecated for DotNetZip, which now supports .NET Core and is actively maintained. I would suggest giving that a shot.